# need assistance setting up wired internet on ubuntu sacy(13.10)

Tags: networking, 13.10, ethernet

im on a state internet and  I need a need assistance setting up my ip. On windows 7 it was easy. but on ubuntu it is a a bit difficult. My school use Alt DNS as well as DNS and my ip never changes but I have to enter it into a field but I don't know where it uses subnet and default gateway how would I enter it please help and thank you please contact if you need additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration of nic is thesame for win and linux. Check if your nic in win set do get data from dhcp, if yes in Network-manager set this option for nic.

You have configuration manual [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-help/net-manual.html)

Maybe you got ip param based on the mac address of nic. If answer is yes, you must change mac address.
Easiest way to change mac address on nic is:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Where xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx represent mac addressc address of nic card.

Comment: thank you the manual helped me the most the net is still down at the school so I have to wait and see if it will work